# Hierarchical data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, recursion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

hey I have a companies table in Snowflake with below definition. I have added screenshot of the source table data and what the desired target view data should look like. I have also added a code I wrote for the view but it is not producing the results in right way.

The Table is called COMPANIES, the view is called CompanyHierarchyView. The level we would love to go till is seven. In the output result I have only added till level 3 for reference.

Also need to do this in SQL and not in other languages like python or Java because of limitation of coding knowledge in the team

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE COMPANIES 

(PARENTCOMPANY VARCHAR(1000),
PARENTID int,
CHILDCOMPANY VARCHAR(1000),
CHILDID int
);

The data in the table is as below:
   Parent Company   Parent ID   Child Company   Child ID
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Acrylic Software    5
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   American Journalism Project 6
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Caffeinated Mind, Inc.  7
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Confirm Inc.    8
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Digital Staircase Inc.  9
Meta Platforms, Inc.    1   Facebook Technologies, LLC  4
Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2   Accipiter Solutions, LLC    3
Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2   Atlas NetConventions, Inc.  10
Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2   Go Toast, LLC   11
Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2   Ad4ever Inc.    12
Atlas Solutions, Inc.   2   Atleas Search   13
Accipiter Solutions, LLC    3   BidClix, Inc.   14
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Jenkins Software LLC    15
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Nimble VR   16
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   13th Lab AB 17
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Armature Studios LLC    18
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Beat Games s.r.o    19
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   BigBox VR, Inc. 20
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Camouflaj LLC   21
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Carbon Design Group, Inc.   22
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   Downpour Interactive, LLC   23
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   ImagineOptix Corporation    24
Facebook Technologies, LLC  4   InfiniLED Limited   25


And I would like to create a view which produces results like this:

  Parent Company    Child Company1  Child Company2  Child Company3
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Acrylic Software        
Meta Platforms, Inc.    American Journalism Project     
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Caffeinated Mind, Inc.      
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Confirm Inc.        
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Digital Staircase Inc.      
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Jenkins Software LLC    
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Nimble VR   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  13th Lab AB 
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Armature Studios LLC    
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Beat Games s.r.o    
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  BigBox VR, Inc. 
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Camouflaj LLC   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Carbon Design Group, Inc.   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  Downpour Interactive, LLC   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  ImagineOptix Corporation    
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Facebook Technologies, LLC  InfiniLED Limited   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Atlas Solutions, Inc.   Accipiter Solutions, LLC    BidClix, Inc.
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Atlas Solutions, Inc.   Atlas NetConventions, Inc.  
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Atlas Solutions, Inc.   Go Toast, LLC   
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Atlas Solutions, Inc.   Ad4ever Inc.    
Meta Platforms, Inc.    Atlas Solutions, Inc.   Atleas Search   

I have below code written but it is not producing right results. Can someone help:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CompanyHierarchyView AS
WITH RECURSIVE CompanyHierarchy AS (
  SELECT
    PARENTCOMPANY AS ParentCompany,
    PARENTID,
    CHILDCOMPANY AS ChildCompany,
    CHILDID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTCOMPANY, PARENTID ORDER BY CHILDID) AS ChildNum
  FROM COMPANIES -- Replace with your table name
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    t.PARENTCOMPANY AS ParentCompany,
    t.PARENTID,
    t.CHILDCOMPANY AS ChildCompany,
    t.CHILDID,
    c.ChildNum
  FROM COMPANIES t
  INNER JOIN CompanyHierarchy c ON t.PARENTID = c.CHILDID
)
SELECT
  ParentCompany,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 1 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company1",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 2 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company2",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 3 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company3",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 4 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company4",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 5 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company5",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 6 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company6",
  MAX(CASE WHEN ChildNum = 7 THEN ChildCompany ELSE NULL END) AS "Child Company7"
FROM CompanyHierarchy
GROUP BY ParentCompany, PARENTID
ORDER BY 1, 2, 7;
```

Would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view will reformat the parent child table to a levels table. The view adds a new row where the top level company is a child of Null. If this row existed in your data, this row would not be required. Also note that the view uses • to delimit the concatenated levels, but any character that does not appear in a company name can be used.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW COMPANYHIERARCHYVIEW AS
WITH COMPANYPC AS (
    SELECT
        PARENTCOMPANY,
        PARENTID,
        CHILDCOMPANY,
        CHILDID
    FROM COMPANIES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'Meta Platforms, Inc.',
        1
)
, CREATE_LEVELS AS
(
    SELECT
        CHILDID,
        CHILDCOMPANY,
        CHILDCOMPANY LEVEL_NAME
    FROM COMPANYPC
    WHERE PARENTID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        COMPANYPC.CHILDID,
        COMPANYPC.CHILDCOMPANY,
        CONCAT( IFNULL(CREATE_LEVELS.LEVEL_NAME || '•','') , COMPANYPC.CHILDCOMPANY)
    FROM COMPANYPC JOIN CREATE_LEVELS
    ON COMPANYPC.PARENTID = CREATE_LEVELS.CHILDID
)
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 1) PARENTCOMPANY,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 2),'') CHILDCOMPANY1,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 3),'') CHILDCOMPANY2,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 4),'') CHILDCOMPANY3,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 5),'') CHILDCOMPANY4,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 6),'') CHILDCOMPANY5,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 7),'') CHILDCOMPANY6,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 8),'') CHILDCOMPANY7
FROM CREATE_LEVELS;
```

If the top level rows with NULL parents exist in the table, then the view would be as follows:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW COMPANYHIERARCHYVIEW AS
WITH CREATE_LEVELS AS
(
    SELECT
        CHILDID,
        CHILDCOMPANY,
        CHILDCOMPANY LEVEL_NAME
    FROM COMPANIES
    WHERE PARENTID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        COMPANIES.CHILDID,
        COMPANIES.CHILDCOMPANY,
        CONCAT( IFNULL(CREATE_LEVELS.LEVEL_NAME || '•','') , COMPANIES.CHILDCOMPANY)
    FROM COMPANIES JOIN CREATE_LEVELS
    ON COMPANIES.PARENTID = CREATE_LEVELS.CHILDID
)
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 1) PARENTCOMPANY,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 2),'') CHILDCOMPANY1,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 3),'') CHILDCOMPANY2,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 4),'') CHILDCOMPANY3,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 5),'') CHILDCOMPANY4,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 6),'') CHILDCOMPANY5,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 7),'') CHILDCOMPANY6,
    NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(LEVEL_NAME, '•', 8),'') CHILDCOMPANY7
FROM CREATE_LEVELS;
```

[image: Results]

Comment: This is adding records for NULL for parent company Meta and also add two records for  Meta>Atlas>Accipitier and Meta>Atlas>Accipitier>BidClix , Also how can I make it dynamic so that "Meta" is not hard coded and if the table has more then one parent company then those hierarchies can also be pulled up. I can make parentid for the parent companies to be null if that helps

Comment: Yes, if you have rows in the table where the top level companies appear as children of Parent = Null, then you can avoid the UNION with the dummy row.

Comment: I removed the hardcoded value for the table which had the value as NULL for Parent. Now it is giving lower level records as well. Can you please help with what the modified code will look like for the table with  null parentid for the top level hierarchy record

Comment: Answer edited with a second view definition to use when the top level rows are in the table with NULL parents.

Comment: you are awesome, this works now. However there is a small modification required. How can we get rid of the record with just Parent company name in it and rest all null. And similarly two records are there one for hierarchy Meta>Atlas>Accipitier  and Meta>Atlas>Accipitier>BidClix. I believe for this code if the hierarchy goes above level 2 it starts making entries for each hierarchy path. We kind of have to the just one entry for the longest path

Comment: That is tricky, but can be done if you can add one more column to the table. (1) Add column LEAF BOOLEAN. (2) Set the value to TRUE for the bottom level companies that have no children. (3) Set it to FALSE for companies that have children. (4) Add LEAF to the column selection list in both sections of the UNION. (5) Add WHERE LEAF = TRUE to the final select from CREATE_LEVELS.

Comment: If you are not able to add the LEAF column, then you can add the following filter to the select from CREATE_LEVELS: WHERE  CHILDID NOT IN (SELECT PARENTID FROM COMPANIES). This will be slower than having the LEAF column, but less maintenance.